# PostgreSQL partitioning syntax FOR VALUES

Tags: postgresql, syntax, partitioning

I'm working on table partitioning in PostgreSQL.

I created a partition for my master table:

```
CREATE TABLE head_partition_table PARTITION OF master_table 
FOR VALUES FROM (DATE_START) TO (DATE_END)
PARTITION BY RANGE (ENTITY_ID, GROUP_NAME);
```

After that, I want to divide `head_partition_table` into smaller partitions, so I wrote code:

```
CREATE TABLE subpartition_table OF head_partititon_table 
FOR VALUES FROM ('0', 'A') TO ('0', 'Z');
```

I can't find how I can specify individual values rather than a range.

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE subpartition_table OF head_partititon_table 
FOR VALUES ('0', 'A');
CREATE TABLE subpartition_table OF head_partititon_table 
FOR VALUES  ('0', 'Z');
```

I get a `syntax error at or near "("`.

Is this possible?

P.S. I tried `PARTITION BY LIST`, but in that case, I can use just one field.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name, PostgreSQL 11.2

Comment: Are you looking for a default partition that takes everything that's not covered by the defined partitions?

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name, I want to set defined partitions without declaring values in range, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could partition these by list like you want by introducing another layer of partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE head_partition_table PARTITION OF master_table 
   FOR VALUES FROM ('2019-01-01') TO ('2020-01-01')
   PARTITION BY LIST (entity_id);

CREATE TABLE subpartition1 PARTITION OF head_partition_table
   FOR VALUES IN ('0')
   PARTITION BY LIST (group_name);

CREATE TABLE subsubpartition1 PARTITION OF subpartition1
   FOR VALUES IN ('A');
```

But this is more an academic exercise than something useful.

Anything exceeding a at most few hundred partitions will not perform well at all.

Comment: I have several millions of rows and have to divide it by date, entity_id and group_name . Solution with range is pretty good for me, but seems that it "smells". The number of partitions approximately will be more than 8k per year. What is the correct way to divide it?

Comment: Several million rows are pretty few. 8000 partitions will kill your performance. Think again why and how you want to partition. Partitioning is good for mass deletions and for sequential scans where the partition key is in the `WHERE` condition. Other operations are usually made *slower* by partitioning. With as little as a couple of million rows it could be best not to partition at all. If you have design questions, perhaps open another question.